# how to uncompress a given string in java recursively?

Tags: java, string, recursion

this is very easy using iteration but i have to do this using recursion. I tried to keep a count of how many times a char occurs in a string, the position and the rest of the string and output.

```
public static String uncompress(String compressedText) {

        return uncompress(compressedText, 1, 0, "");

    }

    public static String uncompress(String text, int count, int pos, String output) {

        if (text.equals("")) {

            return "";
        }

        if (Character.isLetter(text.charAt(pos))) {

            output += text.charAt(0);
            pos++;
        }

        else if(Character.isDigit(text.charAt(pos))) {

            count = text.charAt(pos) - '0';
            output += text.charAt(pos + 1);
            count++;
            pos++;

        }

        text = text.substring(pos + 1);

        uncompress(text, count, pos, output);

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's the question? Question in title but nothing in the body.

Comment: how can i uncompress a give string eg: "3b2a" ---- bbbaa. and i have my code which i am working on..

Comment: Why do you want to do this recursively -- is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in your code such as:

- you are substringing but also passing in a position, you should do one or the other
- your base case is returning "" but instead it should return the accrued string 'output'
- where you recurse you disregard the output from the returning method and just return the output in the current method so nothing is built up by the recursion

Below is code which uses only recursion both to parse the string and build up the output.  I have added comments to show what is happening in the code.  Note that, particularly in recursion, it is useful to have a printout of the current state so you can see what is happening at each stage so I have added this too.

Note that the getMultiple() method is in itself a very simple example of how recursion should work - that you call the same method but either A) pass in some work done in the current call so that it can be accrued by the base case or B) take the output of the method and add something to it / modify it before returning the modified output.

```
public class Recursion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(uncompress("10a2b"));
}

public static String uncompress(String compressedText) {

    return uncompress(compressedText, "", "");

}

public static String getMultiple(char x, int N) {
    if (N == 0) return "";

    return ""+x+getMultiple(x,N-1);
}

public static String uncompress(String text, String count, String output) {
    System.out.println("----");
    System.out.println("TEXT:"+text);
    System.out.println("COUNT:"+count);
    System.out.println("OUTPUT:"+output);


    if (text.equals("")) {
        //base case - no text left to parse

        return output;
    }

    if (Character.isLetter(text.charAt(0))) {
        //letter case - need to take the count we have accrued, parse it into an integer and add to output

        System.out.println(count);// * text.charAt(0);

        output += getMultiple(text.charAt(0),Integer.parseInt(count));

        count = "";
    }

    else if(Character.isDigit(text.charAt(0))) {
        //digit case - need to add to the count but keep as a string because must be parsed later

        count += (""+text.charAt(0));

    }

    //parse the *remainder* of the string, one character at a time, so pass in the substring(1)


      return uncompress(text.substring(1), count, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer, that give response and the know how. I hope that OP will understant it, not only copy paste.

Comment: @Vash: why did you delete your answer for the thread on [dynamic-mouse-listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290340/dynamic-mouse-listeners)? I thought that it was quite intriguing and useful, and it taught me something new. I was just about to up-vote it when it disappeared.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, i was really tired, and the example was not implementing all logic that OP described. I've undeleted it and later i will add missing logic to it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input String has a correct format, try this:

```
public static String uncompress(String compressedText) {
    if (compressedText.length() == 0)
        return "";
    return uncompress(compressedText, charToInt(compressedText, 0), 0);
}

public static String uncompress(String text, int count, int pos) {
    if (pos == text.length() || (pos == text.length()-2 && count == 0))
        return "";
    else if (count == 0)
        return uncompress(text, charToInt(text, pos+2), pos+2);
    return text.charAt(pos+1) + uncompress(text, count-1, pos);
}

public static int charToInt(String str, int idx) {
    return str.charAt(idx) - '0';
}
```